# Laravel. Blade. Могут ли разные методы контроллера возвращать один и тот же view с разным содержимым?

Tags: laravel, view

Есть два, вот таких маршрута:

```
Route::get('/news',                 ['as' => 'news',    'uses' => 'NewsController@index']);
Route::get('/news/championsleague', ['as' => 'newslch', 'uses' => 'NewsController@championsLeague']);
```

В контроллере два метода для них:

раз:

```
$Allnews = $news->getAllNews();

$data = [
    'Allnews'       => $Allnews,
    'MainMenu'      => $menu->getMainOptions()->toArray(),
    'SubMenu'       => $subm->getSubOptions()->toArray(),
];

return view('news', $data);
```

два:

```
$Allnews = $news->getAllLChNews();

$data = [
    'Allnews'       => $Allnews,
    'MainMenu'      => $menu->getMainOptions()->toArray(),
    'SubMenu'       => $subm->getSubOptions()->toArray(),
];

return view('news', $data);
```

Первая страница, по маршруту "/news" отображается нормально (её метод первый). А вот второй маршрут "/news/championsleague" (соответственно второй метод), выводят в браузер страницу без стилей!

Общая вьюха news.blade.php наследует основной лэйаут, где содержимое тега head, главное меню, и футер. Почему второй метод выдаёт страницу без стилей? В коде страницы в браузере, в заголовке есть линки на стили? Попробовал создать отдельный файл с таким же содержанием, но просто назвал по другому, но увы страница опять без стилей. Что за чудеса, помогите дилетанту...

Answer (score 1):

Не по-детски туплю. Дела тут совсем не в маршрутах, и даже не в контроллерах. Всё куда намного проще. Просто в наследуемом лэйауте вьюхой news.blade.php, в заголовке пути на стили были относительными. Вся проблема заключалась в паре слэшей в двух линках.